# What does this mean in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, action

Hello I've started to learning AS3 from one book and found something I don't understand.

```
Ellipse(_board[row][column]).fill = getFill(row, column);
```

- `_board` is two dimensional array of `Ellipse` type, so I just dont understand why is `Ellipse(Ellipse object)` used when it apparently works without it, or I haven't seen any changes when I omitted it.

Comment: When you omit what? The reference to _board? The reference to Ellipse?

Comment: Yes  reference to Ellipse, as I dont know why it is used that way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ellipse(_board[row][column])` is a [type cast](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87.html) `Type(object)` 
Because you can push anything into an `Array` the compiler doesn't know what kind of objects are stored within the `Array`. So it is good style to cast objects if you retrive them from an `Array` to their correct type.

This has several benefits:

- if such an object is not of the type you expect or null, you will know when you typecast instead of getting an error later somewhere far away
- the code executes a bit faster if you are explicit about the types
- if you use a good IDE it can provide you with autocompletion when it knows the types

Comment: Thanks for explanation, AS3 casting syntax confused me a little

Answer (score 0):

_board is a multidimensional array filled first with Arrays.
In the BoardDisplay.mxml

**(Hello! Flex 4 : Chapter 3. Hello Spark: primitives, comp... > FXG and MXML graphics—building a game.. - Pg. 80)** ,

```
<Graphic version="1.0" viewHeight="601" viewWidth="701"
  xmlns=" library://ns. adobe. com/flex/spark"
  xmlns:fx=" http://ns. adobe. com/mxml/2009"
  xmlns:mx=" library://ns. adobe. com/flex/halo"
  initialize="createBoard()"
  click=" clickHandler(event)">
```

initialize calls createBoard().

```
private function createBoard():void {
    newGame();
    _board = new Array(6);
    for (var row:int = 0; row < 6; row++) {
        _board[row] = new Array(7);
        for (var col:int = 0; col < 7; col++) {
            _board[row][col] = addEllipse(row, col); //Magic Happens!
        }
    }
}
```

addEllipse returns Ellipse to each entry in _board

```
private function addEllipse(row:int, col:int):Ellipse {
    var ellipse:Ellipse = new Ellipse();
    ellipse.x = 4 + col*100;
    ellipse.y = 5 + row*100;
    ellipse.width = 90;
    ellipse.height = 90;
    ellipse.fill = getFill(row,col); // Magic Found !
    ellipse.stroke = new SolidColorStroke(0x000000, 1, 1.0, false,"normal", null, "miter", 4);
    boardGroup.addElement(ellipse);
    return ellipse;
}
```

The author casted it as maxmx said but did not really need to as all the entries were of type Ellipse so

```
Ellipse(_board[row][column]).fill = getFill(row, column);
```

can work as

```
_board[row][column].fill = getFill(row, column);
```